# Cruise Control losing track of paths in subtasks

Tags: ant, cruisecontrol

We have some projects in cruise control, set up roughly like this:

Cruise Control

```
<ant antfile="build.xml" dir="A" target="compile" inheritAll="false" />
```

in **A** the compile target calls, as a part of its compile, a jar target in **B**
 (in "compile")

```
<ant antfile="${B.dir}/build.xml" inheritAll="false" target="jar" />
<javac ... >
```

So **B** has a jar task.**A** builds the jar from **B** and then uses it in it's compile.

The problem I'm running into is that cruise control seems to confuse the paths. Although the **A** compile task works directly from ant, when run from cruisecontrol it seems to be trying to find it's own internal libraries based on paths from the **B** jar settings.

To get this to work in ant I had to call **B** from **A** using the inheritAll="false" flag, but neither this nor calling javac with fork seems to resolve the problem.

Possibly related- we're running ant @ version 1.7, the cc server is at ant version 1.6.5, which I can't easily update.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

In your CruiseControl configuration you can specify the [anthome or antscript attributes](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/main/configxml.html#ant-examples) so that you use your version of Ant, so you should be able to get the same behavior from CC that you get at the command-line.

Comment: This is a good link. Thanks. However, I'm still stuck, as the anthome/antscript attributes still don't get recognized-do you happen to know if those are new to ant 1.7? if so, then I need to get the ant version fixed. If no, then the cc install is borked. Thanks again for the tip.

Comment: Those attributes are for the CruiseControl config.xml, not the Ant build.xml. You use them to tell CC which Ant it should use for the build.